# Content Type with Tabular Data to be Input

Tags: forms, nodes, theming

I'm building a content type that is going to require tabular data to be input. Here's a mockup of what the table should look like:
[image: mockup of data table]
Rows 1 and 2 are fixed headers, 3-6 are data.

I am at a total loss as to how I should build this. I've experiemented with a few modules (like [TableField](https://drupal.org/project/tablefield)... which is not really what I'm looking for).

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a module that I'm not aware of that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use [field_collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection)? (separate the E.Coli in 2 fields EColiB and EColiE ... and maybe some CSS to style it) - perhaps this is not a solution, I am posting it here since I am couple of points short and cannot leave comments for additional info under the original post

Comment: There is actually [field_collection_table](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table).